# SQLite has no looping. How can I accomplish looping?

Tags: sql, sqlite, loops, row

I understand QLite has no looping.  Here is what I want to accomplish.  I have a single row that has values (horizontal): 
'1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10'

I want to display it vertically as:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

In Oracle I can accomplish this using a loop and function REGEXP_SUBSTR. How can I accomplis this with SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with a recursive [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
CREATE TABLE t(x);
INSERT INTO t VALUES('1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10');

WITH RECURSIVE split(val, rest) AS (
  SELECT NULL,
         x || ':'
  FROM t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT substr(rest, 1, instr(rest, ':') - 1),
         substr(rest, instr(rest, ':') + 1)
  FROM split
  WHERE rest != ''
)
SELECT val
FROM split
WHERE val IS NOT NULL;
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```